# How to remove form EventSubscriber on Form Type Extension?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I want to override the EventSubscriber on a form but unfortunately it's not a service so I cannot decorate it.

Alternatively, would like to override the form and remove the Subscriber and add my custom one.
But I cannot find a way to remove it...

Comment: from a FormConfigBuilder (i.e. inside `buildForm`) you can [get the event dispatcher](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/885390fbaf95ff1266ed04e5fe1b99da4a24d18b/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormConfigBuilder.php#L225) and manage the listeners/subscribers via its interface: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.1/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcherInterface.php

Comment: Tried but not working...

Comment: At the end, I decorate the form type instead of type extension to make it works.